# Fetch data from MongoDB when the user register

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

I am learning MEAN stack environment and I have a question.

I have a registration page, which registers the user in MongoDB:

```
// register.component.ts
 
register(){
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3001/register', this.input)
        .subscribe(
          (            next: any) => {
                // TO-DO Success event
                 
            },
          (            error: any) => {
                // TO-DO Error event
                 
            });
}
```

```
    // app.js
     
    app.post('/register', function(req, res){
        db.collection('users').insertOne({
            prenom : req.body.prenom,
            nom: req.body.nom,
            email : req.body.email,
            password : req.body.password
        })
         
    })
```

It works pretty well, the problem is that for the connection, I use the _id:

```
// login.component.ts
 
  login(id: string){
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3001/login/' + id).toPromise().then((data: any) => {
      this.users = data
   
    
      
    })
    sessionStorage.setItem('id', id)
     
  }
```

```
// app.js
 

    app.get('/login/:id', function(req, res){
        db.collection('users').findOne({ email: ObjectId(`${req.params.id}`)}, function(err, user){
            if (err) throw err;
            if (!user) {
                console.log('User not found')
            }
            else if (user)
            {
                console.log('Found user: ' + user.prenom)
            }
        })
    })
```

**How to make sure that when the user registers, it returns his _id directly, and like that I can put him in session:**

```
sessionStorage.setItem('id', id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `db.collection.insertOne()` function returns the inserted document, see [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/). This means you can do a callback or async/await (whichever you prefer) for your `insertOne()` function and then return the `_id` by using the Express function `res.json()`. In your frontend, you'll then get whatever content you put into `res.json()` as a response. Happy coding! :)

Comment: Thank you, it does work !
Now, how can I convert into a string ? Because it returns an error when I try to assign it as a session value :

Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Comment: Nevermind, found it, thank you ! sessionStorage.setItem('id', JSON.stringify(result))